# Birt/tomcat: set session variable after j_security_check

Tags: jsp, tomcat, j-security-check

I am using a form based authentication in tomcat and in action am using j_security_check. The code is below

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Login to the Tomcat-Demo application:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="j_password"/ ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I would like to use the user that has logged in in the report. I would like to catch the logged user from the session. My idea was to use the following jsp syntax to set the variable

```
<%
        session.setAttribute("myName",request.getParameter("user"));
%>
```

HOwever, I am not sure how to set the session variable like this because soon after the authentication, it is redirected to the requested URL

Can someon please help

Regards
Arif

Comment: do you want to put that name in your login form? or get the username once authenticated?

Comment: both way is fine as long as I can get the username who has logged in. In the report I want to show the data that the user is allowed to see. For that I need to retrieve the user that has logged in

Answer (score 0):

usually solved over filters.
check the tomcat docu for filters, and apply your filter (maybe to match every request, since you can not apply it. google for the keywords session, filter, principal.

```
dofilter() {
    getSession;
    if(session->user is not set) {
        session->user = request->getPrincipal->getUsername() //something like that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once authenticated you can fetch the corresponding username from the request by a call to :

```
request.getRemoteUser()
```

You can also test if the user has a specific role by a call to

```
request.isUserInRole()
```

This can be donne anywhere you have access to the HttpServletRequest

See the servlet API for more details.